# Java Script Get Number of index for array from text box

Tags: javascript, arrays, web

So here is the problem.I want user to enter number of index in text box for array. After taking index i want user to enter value from a prompt box to store in that array but that prompt box is coming over and over again and i have to click on button every time to take input
Here is the code

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <label> Enter Number of Records </label>
    <input type="text" id="t1">
    <input type="button" value="Enter" onClick="record()">

    <h1 id="demo"></h1>

    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Java Script:

```
var data = document.getElementById("t1").value;
function record(){
    var crap = new Array(data);
    for(var i=0;i<crap.length;i++){
        crap[i] = prompt("Add something in my array","");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += crap[i]+"<br>";
    }
```

Comment: Because you are using it in a loop, so the `prompt` will execute for each array element. Also do you want to enter something and place it in a certain index of the array, or simply push it at the end of the array?

Comment: _I want user to enter number of index in text box for array_ can you please clarify what exactly you are looking for

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek i just want enter any thing in array

Comment: @user2181397 i wanna say that user will enter any number in textbox and then that number will become index for array
let suppose user enter 6 in array then index of Array become 6 , so that user can enter 6 record using prompt and store it in array

Comment: Do you mean the *length* of the array will be 6? Index is a position in the array, not the length.

Comment: @AhmedAbbas Then elements in an array have indexes to them, I don't think you are meaning the index of some element in the array. I think you mean you just want to add the element to the end of the array, which in that case you can use `.push()`.

Comment: Javascript doesn't require you to set the length of an array before using it. You can just keep adding items to the array with `array.push()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you are retrieving `data` outside the function. Thus its value will be 'undefined' and the `crap` will became the array of one value that is `undefined`. So `crap.length` will be always 1.

Try this:
`function record(){
            var data = document.getElementById("t1").value;
            var crap = []
            if(crap != undefined)
            for(var i=0;i<data;i++){
                var tmp = prompt("Add something in my array","");
                crap.push(tmp);
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += crap[i]+"<br>";
            }
        }`
Enjoy coding ....

Answer (score 0):

Try this,This will solve your issue.

You are just declaring an array named `crap`, **and you are trying to get the `crap.length` even before the array is filled**, so you are getting the issue. Since data has your value try looping with `data` value.

```js
function record(){
            data = document.getElementById("t1").value;
     var crap = new Array(parseInt(data)); // you should take data here,  since crap is empty at this point.
            console.log(data)
     for(var i=0;i<data;i++){
  crap[i] = prompt("Add something in my array","");
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += crap[i]+"<br>";
     }
 }
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    </head>

    <body>
    <label> Enter Number of Records </label>
    <input type="text" id="t1">
    <input type="button" value="Enter" onClick="record()">

    <h1 id="demo"></h1>

    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please run the code snippet and check the answer.

Comment: Why are you putting `data` into the array, then overwriting it in the loop?

Comment: data is just in the function, but not in the loop, `crap.length` has nothing to do, since array is empty at that point, please run the code snippet and check.

Comment: `crap = new Array(data)` is the sane as `crap = [data]` when `data` is something other than an integer.

Comment: I meant you're initially setting `crap[0]` to `data`, then the first element of the loop will set `crap[0]` to the response to the "Add something" prompt

Comment: As the data element has the number of elements needed to be stored in an array, I have looped the data itself, any ways only based on this data value, the array length will be decided.

Comment: `data` is a string, not a number. You need to use `parseInt()`.

Comment: But there's no need to set the length of the array. It will grow automatically when you add elements to it.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek i want some thing like this

Comment: @ChetanRaikwal i want something like this

Comment: @Barmar, user any ways enter the number in that field, even it is a string for eg:("5"), it can still work in the for loop, 
Eg:  `for(var i=0;i<parseInt(5);i++)` or `for(var i=0;i<"5";i++)` giving the same result/

Comment: The `for` loop is fine because `<` automatically converts the string to a number. I'm talking about `var crap = new Array(data)`. That creates an array with 1 element whose value is `data`, it doesn't create an array whose length is `data`.

Comment: @Barmar,  okay, even  though my answer is working fine, but as you said I am adding `parseInt()` before that data, thank you.

Comment: @AhmedAbbas, if my answer helped you, you can vote it up, have a good day.